# session flashdata not work correctly in codeigniter 2.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have a problem with session flashdata. never the message containing the session is displayed. I read many post on the page. but i don't found a solution to the problem

I have this routes:

```
//index is a subfolder into the controllers folder
//user is a controller
$route['login']             = 'index/user/showLogin';
$route['do_login']          = 'index/user/doLogin';
$route['register']          = 'index/user/showRegister';
$route['do_register']       = 'index/user/doRegister';
```

user.php controller:

```
public function showRegister()
{
   $this->template->set('title', 'test register');
   $this->template->load('template', 'index/register', $data);
}

public function doRegister()
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email',      'Email',                'required|trim|max_length[30]|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password',   'Password',           'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|xss_clean|alpha_dash');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('rrpassword', 'Re Password',   'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|xss_clean|matches[password]|alpha_dash');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
    $this->showRegister();
   }
   else
   {
       $email      = $this->input->post('email');
       $pass       = $this->input->post('password');
       $password   = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($pass);

       // check if the password was encrypted
       if ($this->bcrypt->check_password($pass, $password))
       {
           $data =array(
               'email'     => $email,
               'password'  => $password,
           );

           $insert = $this->user_model->register($data);

           if(!$insert)
           {
               echo 'error';
           }
           $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'registered');
           redirect('login', 'refresh');
       }
       else
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'Oops.. error...');
           redirect(base_url('login'), 'refresh');
       }
    }
  }
```

to display messages I do this in the view "login":

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
   Test: <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('info'); ?>
</div>
```

But never the message is printed. i Tried this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'test......');
$this->session->keep_flashdata('info');
redirect('login', 'refresh');
```

But not works. Also add the favicon.ico to the root folder, but does not work. I'm trying to fix it a few hours ago. It may be the version of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

have you load the `session` library . I think `session` library is not loaded by default.

try loading `session` library in your function before you calling to `flashdata` or load session library inside the `constructor`

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

or add session library to `config/autoload.php`

Comment: Obviously had already configured the autoload file. I'm not so noob haha

Comment: @OsquiB ok Then do it your self